# How to prevent losing commit history in Subversion after merges?

Tags: svn

Setup simple SVN project  layout:

```
svnadmin create proj-repo
svn co file://$PWD/proj-repo proj
cd proj
mkdir branches trunk tags features
svn add *
svn ci -m 'Basic SVN project setup.'
```

Start project:

```
cd trunk
svn add README
svn ci -m 'Add README'
```

Implement features:

```
svn cp . ^/features/linux-port
cd ../../
svn co file://$PWD/proj-repo/features/linux-port proj-linux-port
cd proj-linux-port
svn ci -m "Implement feature 1."
svn ci -m "Implement feature 2."
svn ci -m 'Add last feature.'
```

Do job in main dev branch:

```
svn switch ^/trunk
svn ci -m "Fix."
```

Ready for new features:

```
svn merge --reintegrate ^/features/linux-port
svn ci -m 'Integrate features.'
```

But now:

```
svn log .

------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9 | user | 2013-07-30 18:38:01 +0300 (Tue, 30 Jul 2013) | 1 line

Integrate features.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | user | 2013-07-30 18:36:53 +0300 (Tue, 30 Jul 2013) | 1 line

Fix.
```

and:

```
svn diff -r9

Index: README
===================================================================
--- README      (revision 8)
+++ README      (revision 9)
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 hello fix

+feature 1
+
+feature 2
+
+final feature

Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Added: svn:mergeinfo
   Merged /features/linux-port:r2-8
```

So I lose subsequent commits for each individual features from `/features/linux-port:r2-8`. Is it possible to preserve them without switching to HG/Git/Bzr/Fossil?

**UPDATE** We usually write good commit messages where explain coding decision and put links to BTS. SVN erase these info and we're very sad.

So we need use old school [Changelog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changelog)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I just carefully read:

```
svn help log

  -g [--use-merge-history] : use/display additional information from merge
```

So full history available with usual SVN tools.

To see actual diff use hat path syntax:

```
svn diff -c 4 ^/
```

Also I found apropriate section in official docs:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html

```
The svn blame command also takes the --use-merge-history (-g) option.
If this option is neglected, somebody looking at a line-by-line annotation
of file may get the mistaken impression that you were responsible for the lines
that fixed a certain error
```

Comment: Hah, I was about to say this, indeed, that's how it's done. I usually set something like `alias svnmlog='svn log -g'`  to make sure I don't forget.
`